# Counting values in multiple columns

Tags: r

everyone.
Here's the problem:

```
Column1  Column2
da          fa
fa          da
ra          da
ta          ta
```

I need to count how many times each string appears in both columns: I mean, "da" appears 1 time in Column1 and 2 times in Column2, so I need the count of 3. Ps.: I can't stack them, because it will generate new rows with null values in my dataframe.

Comment: Use `table`: `table(unlist(df))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% count(value)
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  value     n
  <chr> <int>
1 da        3
2 fa        2
3 ra        1
4 ta        2
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sum` on a logical matrix to return the count as `TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0 in `base R`

```
sum(df1 == "da", na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 3
```

If we need it by columns, use `colSums`

```
colSums(df1 == "da", na.rm = TRUE)
Column1 Column2 
      1       2
```

---

If we want all the frequency counts in `base R`

```
table(stack(df1)$values)

da fa ra ta 
 3  2  1  2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Column1 = c("da", "fa", "ra", "ta"), Column2 = c("fa", 
"da", "da", "ta")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```